# Adding an element to linked list?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

This is my struct and method but it's not working. Can anyone help me where is the problem? Thanks

this is struct:

```
    struct album
{
    char singerName[30];
    char year[4];
    char title[30];

    char songName[50];
    char songLength[50];
    struct album *next;
};
struct album *a=NULL;
```

This is the method:

```
struct album *addAlbum(struct album *list,char* year,char *title,char *singerName)
{
    struct album *temp;
    temp =(struct album*) malloc(sizeof(struct album));
    strcpy(temp->singerName,singerName);
    strcpy(temp->title,title);
    strcpy(temp->year,year);
    temp -> next = NULL;

    if(list==NULL)
    {
        return temp;
    }
    else
    {
   temp->next=list;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Homework time (again). Please supply code that compiles and demonstrates the problem

Comment: If you can't do your homework yourself, could you at least point out what the compiler says about the nature and location of the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please rad the [About] page soon. You've only allocated 4 characters for the year; that should probably be 5 to allow for 4-digit years.  Arguably, you should be doing length-checked copies to the members of your allocated structure.  You can simplify the code by using `temp->next = list;` without the conditions (if list is NULL, it will be correct, and if it is not it will be correct) then `return temp;`.  In what way is not working? And what does the code calling this function look like?

Comment: Not a relevant question.

Comment: "It's not working" - what is that supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1):

Insufficient control on destination buffer.

The following will likely fail if the input `year` is "2013".  This is a string, needing 4+1 bytes.

```
char year[4];     
...
strcpy(temp->year,year);
```

Simple fix is to use `char year[5]`. But that kicks the can down the road.

Better to use `strncpy(temp->year,year, sizeof(temp->year)-1); temp->year[sizeof(temp->year)-1] = '\0'`.  Other options exists to prevent overrun.